# Can lattice join be an element of residuated pair?

Tags: lattice-theory, galois-connection

Given a classic (not Residuated) lattice, with standard definition of partial order via lattice join and meet operations, is it possible to satisfy Galois equivalence
$$
    (x \vee y) < z \;\Longleftrightarrow\;  x < (y / z).
$$
for some binary operation $/$ ?

Edit: One way to answer this is putting lattice axioms together with Galois condition into something like Mace4. Then finite model search reveals that lattice join $\vee$ appears to have no adjoints, while meet $\wedge$ has. The question is more subtle, however: is there adjoint for lattice meet operation in any lattice model?

Comment: Consider what happens when $y>z$. You cannot dualize only some parts of the definition of a Heityng algebra and blindly hope to obtain something useful.